# Python: Barplot similar to embedded picture

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, seaborn

I found a nice barplot in a paper and want to make something similar, but don't know how. The figure I wish to make is the following

[image]
I made the following replicable example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, seaborn as sns;
data = np.array([[0.3,0.4,0.7],
                [0.5, 0.3,  0.8 ],
                [0.7,0.2,0.5],
                [0.2,0.4,0.1],
                [0.3,0.1, 0.8],
                [0.5,0.9, 0.2],
                [1.4,1.7,1.2],
                [0.4,0.8, 0.3],
                [1.8,2.6, 0.4],
                [2.7,3.7, 2.1],
                [0.1,4.1, 2.4]])
data_df =  pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['SMB', 'HML', 'MOM'], index = ['OLS3', 'EN', 'GLM', 'NN1','NN2','NN3','NN4','NN5','NN6', 'NN7','NN7'])
```

I then tried creating a barplot like this:

```
data_df.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(16, 10))
```

But this is not really what I'm looking for. Does anyone know how to make similar to the picture I added?

Comment: I don't see any major difference between the result of the code and the expected output. What exactly do you not like about the output?

Comment: I would like the horizontal axis labels to be curved like in the picture. Moreover, I would like the 'timeline effect' that the picture has (i.e. small vertical lines for the categories OLS PLS etc.). And the black line at y=0 as well.

Comment: The vertical lines are called "grid". A "horizontal line" is searchable by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, seaborn as sns;
data = np.array([[0.3,0.4,0.7],
                [0.5, 0.3,  0.8 ],
                [0.7,0.2,0.5],
                [0.2,0.4,0.1],
                [0.3,0.1, 0.8],
                [0.5,0.9, 0.2],
                [1.4,1.7,1.2],
                [0.4,0.8, 0.3],
                [1.8,2.6, 0.4],
                [2.7,3.7, 2.1],
                [0.1,4.1, 2.4]])
data_df =  pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['SMB', 'HML', 'MOM'], index = ['OLS3', 'EN', 'GLM', 'NN1','NN2','NN3','NN4','NN5','NN6', 'NN7','NN7'])
ax=data_df.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(16, 10),fontsize=15)
plt.xticks(rotation=-45)
#set ylim
plt.ylim(-0.5, 4.5)
#grid on
plt.grid()
# set y=0
ax.axhline(0, color='black', lw=1)
#change size of legend
ax.legend(fontsize=20)
#hiding upper and right axis layout
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
#changing the thickness
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(3)
ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(3)
```

Output:

[image]